# Cannot load swf file runtime

Tags: javascript, php, html, flash

I am adding a flvplayer runtime. When i am adding it on runtime it is not working but after reloading the page it is working fine.

Please take a look at my php and html code:-

```
function crete_template(record){
{
var tpl ='<object id="player" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" name="player" width="328" height="200">'+
                            '<param name="movie" class="movie" value="<?php echo JSPATH;?>player/player.swf" />'+
                            '<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />'+
                            '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />'+
                            '<param name="flashvars" value="file=<?php echo UPLOAD_PATH; ?>'+record.video_file+'" />'+
                            '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="<?php echo JSPATH;?>player/player.swf" width="400" eight="200">'+
                                '<param name="movie" class="movie" value="<?php echo JSPATH;?>player/player.swf" />'+
                                '<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />'+
                                '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />'+
                                '<param name="flashvars" value="file=<?php echo UPLOAD_PATH; ?>'+record.video_file+'" />'+
                                '<p><a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer">Get Flash</a> to see this player.</p>'+
                            '</object>'+
                        '</object>';
return $(tpl);
}
```

i am putting the whole html part into a div dynamically.

I am using [this](http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/) player

I think my "player/player.swf" file is not loaded in runtime.
If question is not clear please ask me and help me.

Comment: provide runable demo of your code. which will help to get quick answer.

Comment: @DipaliVasani thnkx for replying i have added the whole function that i have called on runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function crete_template(record){
{
var tpl ='<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="<?php echo JSPATH;?>player/player.swf" width="400" height="200">'+
                            '<param name="movie" class="movie" value="<?php echo JSPATH;?>player/player.swf" />'+
                            '<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />'+
                            '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />'+
                            '<param name="flashvars" value="file=<?php echo UPLOAD_PATH; ?>'+record.video_file+'" />'+
                            '<p><a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer">Get Flash</a> to see this player.</p>'+
                        '</object>';
return $(tpl);
}
```